# Email form won't sent from aol.com yahoo.com addresses

Tags: php, email

My email form is working but will not send an email when the user uses a aol.com and yahoo.com email address. What do I need to change?
PHP file is hosted by godaddy.

I'm a designer, and PHP is not my forte, can you explain an answer with changes to my existing code (if the change is with the code at all.) This problem is very frustrating.

```
 // Only process POST reqeusts.
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    // Get the form fields and remove whitespace.
    $name = strip_tags(trim($_POST["name"]));
            $name = str_replace(array("\r","\n"),array(" "," "),$name);
    $email = filter_var(trim($_POST["email"]), FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
    $message = trim($_POST["message"]);

    // Check that data was sent to the mailer.
    if ( empty($name) OR empty($message) OR !filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        // Set a 400 (bad request) response code and exit.
        // http_response_code(400);
        echo "Oops! There was a problem with your submission. Please complete the form and try again.";
        exit;
    }

    // Set the recipient email address.
    // FIXME: Update this to your desired email address.
    $recipient = "mysite@mysite.com";

    // Set the email subject.
    $subject = "New contact from $name";

    // Build the email content.
    $email_content = "Name: $name\n";
    $email_content .= "Email: $email\n\n";
    $email_content .= "Message:\n$message\n";

    // Build the email headers.
    $email_headers = "From: $name <$email>";

    // Send the email.
    if (mail($recipient, $subject, $email_content, $email_headers)) {
        //Set a 200 (okay) response code.
      //  http_response_code(200);
        echo "Thank You! Your message has been sent.";
    } else {
        // Set a 500 (internal server error) response code.
       // http_response_code(500);
        echo "Oops! Something went wrong and we couldn't send your message.";
    }

} else {
    // Not a POST request, set a 403 (forbidden) response code.
   // http_response_code(403);
    echo "There was a problem with your submission, please try again.";
}
```

Comment: Props for using `filter_var` to validate email addresses.

Comment: Isn't this a catched-in-spam-folder problem ?

Comment: Its not ... not sending, its probably getting caught in your junk mail or spam filter.

Comment: I would guess these guys have SPF policies in place and you are not going to be on that list.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that I can think of is that goDaddy has blocked these domains for sending emails, since mail() uses the servers settings

Answer (score 0):

I also don't see any error in your simple code. Some things to consider:

- Your new lines in the body *and* header should use CRLF `\r\n`, rather simply `\n`
- You may also use *additional parameters* and setting your email as *5th parameter* with the -f command (trusted user for the sending program).

Example:

```
// Send the email.
if (mail($recipient, $subject, $email_content, $email_headers,"-f".$email)) {
```

- Since you're a designer, i also suggest to use tools like **[PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer)**, that eases the e-mailing process and fixes some stuff for you.

Answer (score 0):

Well that's because you're not supposed to be sending mail on behalf of email addresses you don't control through mail servers that are not authorized to do so. This is a rule about email that most people seem to ignore, but both Yahoo and AOL have both recently changed their policies to block the exact thing you are trying to do.

http://blog.mailchimp.com/aol-changes-dmarc-policy/

I would expect that this will become a thing that more and more mail providers do as time goes on.

What you *should* be doing is using an email address that *you own* to send out the mail, either through that domains outbound server or one authorized by the domain, and not trying to spoof someone else's address. In addition to not appearing to be shady as all get-out, you'll be far less likely to run afoul of DMARC and SPF policies, spam filters, and angry email admins perusing StackOverflow.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation however, this is only to receive info via contact form, not for spamming to other email addresses. I realized that this was just heading to my spam folder, it was buried.

Answer (score 0):

I tore out my hair over this issue for weeks.  Finally figured it out today.  If your form has an email field and it's named "email", and the user types an @aol or @yahoo email address, Formmail will act like nothing's wrong, but the form will not be sent.

It's an easy fix.  Just use something else (*anything else* but "email") for the email field name, like "FromEmail".. Easy peasy.

If the user types something like dingbat@aol.com or doofus@yahoo.com:

This won't work:

```
<input type="text" name="email" size="30" maxlength="100" />
```

but this will:

```
<input type="text" name="FromEmail" size="30" maxlength="100" />
```

Good luck!

Chaz